Bypassing a filament cartridge chip / Logic analyzer expert needed!
I have a 3D printer from a manufacturer that has discontinued their PLA filament cartridges. These cartridges were equipped with a chip that seemed to track filament usage. The printer, one of their early models, refuses to continue printing once it determines the filament is depleted. Despite being expensive, it's an excellent printer that I'd like to keep using.
Objective
To use unbranded PLA, I need to hack or bypass the cartridge chip. I'm seeking guidance on how to analyze and potentially emulate the chip's communication with the printer.
Hardware Details

The cartridge's PCB has only two pins
The IC is a 6-pin package without useful labeling
Unknown IC type, communication protocol, and
baud rate

Current Progress

Connected a 24 MHz 8-channel logic analyzer to the two PCB pins

Unsoldered the IC to isolate and read the communication from the printer

Using SALAE Logic 2 software to analyze:

First 60 seconds of communication during printer boot

Communication during cartridge unloading and loading



Installed "Baud rate estimate" extension by Jonathan Reichelt in
Logic 2

Estimated baud rate: 800 kHz (from a 10-second timeframe, seems high)


Next Steps
If I can understand the protocol and baud rate, I plan to resolder the IC and analyze the bidirectional communication.
Request for assistance as I'm not an expert in reverse engineering, I'm seeking advice on the best approach to:

Confirm or correct the baud rate estimation
Identify the communication protocol
Decode the messages between the printer and cartridge chip
Potentially emulate the chip's responses

Any guidance, tools, or techniques that could help in this analysis would be greatly appreciated.




Did you buy this directly from the manufacturer? Have you called (or otherwise communicated with) the manufacturer to find out what they can do for you to solve this problem? If they are refusing to help, tell us the manufacturer name here on the site.

I have a SINDOH DP201 3D printer, which is no longer supported by the manufacturer. SINDOH has discontinued their 3D printer line, dissolved their 3D printer department, and stopped responding to service requests as of last year.

It's quite possible that encryption is used where both sides know the key and it's not disclosed to you. Do you have an unused cartridge that you can use to see what the exchange looks like for "new" cartridges? Better, do you have two of them? You might get lucky. I have two 3D printers here and there is NO possible way I would have bought a cartridge machine with such a gimmick on it. Not without written guarantees, signed and sealed, from the manufacturer about the case where their cartridges are no longer available. I'd make sure of that before buying. So there is also a lesson here.

When I purchased the printer, there was no mention of protection chips in the cartridges. This lack of disclosure is indeed problematic and something I would have considered carefully before buying had I known.
Available Cartridges: Fortunately, I do have two cartridges available for analysis:
a) A new, unused cartridge
b) A cartridge that's giving the "filament has run out" message

Well, I'd give a shot at copying the signalling from the new cartridge. I'd definitely capture it. If there's no identifying information on the new cartridge communications and it is only a "I'm not empty" message or a message with a %full indicator, then you can just repeat it over and over for your own "cartridge." Of course, that may not be enough. I would never buy a cartridge-based machine without first asking about a built-in encoder. I would have been proactive here. Not passive.

Thank you. Very helpful.

You should capture the communications for the same cartridge being inserted into the machine two separate times. If the messages from the machine are completely different each time, the odds are that it is using public-private key encryption (or something similar). In this case, without knowing the keys, you are pretty much stuck. This would prevent solving this by replaying the cartridge response.

FWIW, there's a firmware update for  the DP200 (but apparently not the DP201) that opens up the filament sourcing. Another angle that could be pursued.

@SpehroPefhany Thank you! I am aware of that and we tried to use it. Unfortunately, the DP201 is different and the firmware does not work. It was sent to me in 2022 by a SINDOH engineer when it became clear that they would stop their 3D printer line. The DP201 was developed by a different party.

The IC is likely a 1-Wire EEPROM. One pad (J1/J2) connnects to GND and the other pad connects to the 1-Wire I/O, which also powers the IC. You could try to set your logic analyzer to 1-Wire decoding and see if you can get any meaningful data

@DoxyLover Thank you! At this point, I would need to establish the correct data rate first. Until now, I have not received any useful data stream. The 800 khz estimated by the plugin seems very high.

@Mau5 Thank you! You are probably right. I understand that this is an almost impossible task, but I want to give it a try anyway. The only other alternative would be to somehow obtain the original firmware for the DP201.

@user55272 Chances are good that they just increment or decrement a counter based on the filament usage. You could also read the entire memory of your brand new cartridge, copy it to another 1Wire EEPROM, and see if it works. The new IC does not even need to be the exact same part number

@Mau5 Ok. I have captured around 70 seconds beginning from power on and uploaded the LOGIC 2 file to my Google Drive. This capture is with the 6-pin chip soldered on. Maybe someone with knowledge can see anything meaningful from the data. The 1-wire analyzer shows lots of data, but unfortunately, it does not mean anything to me as I do not know what to look for. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YsFPnsvVzh-Ie704iT-vo2t92VnJ9sg1/view?usp=sharing

Looks like a DS2502P-E48+ or similar IC of the DS2502 chip family.
The pinout is a match and the 1Wire interface is plausible for a memory chip with only two conneted contacts.
It is an OTP type EEPROM memory, data bytes can only be added once.
